# Faithfulness of representations of knot group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It is well known that the knot group of the figure-eight knot has the following presentation

$$G=\langle x,y\mid  xy^{-1}x^{-1}yx=yxy^{-1}x^{-1}y\rangle.$$

For $s\geq \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, set $t=\frac{1}{2(s-1/s)}(1+\sqrt{(s-1/s)^4+2(s-1/s)^2-3})$. One can verify that there is a family of representations $\phi_s: G \to SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with $$\phi_s(x)= \begin{pmatrix} s &0 \\ 0 &1/s \end{pmatrix},\quad \phi_s(y)= \begin{pmatrix} (s+1/s)/2+t & (s-1/s)/2+t \\ (s-1/s)/2-t & (s+1/s)/2-t \end{pmatrix}.$$

Note that this means there are uncountably many such (non-abelian) representations. Can we ensure that there are uncountably many *faithful* representations among them?

I believe the answer is yes. Non-trivial kernel means $\phi(g)=I$ for some $1\not=g\in G$, that is, polynomial equations in $s$ having finitely many solutions. In the meantime, $G$ is countable and so there are only countably many solutions for $s$. But this argument is weak and not rigorous.

Figure-eight knot is hyperbolic. Therefore, there is at least one faithful $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$- representation (not $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$).

In general, I want to ask this question for 2-bridge knots, whose knot group looks like $$G=\langle x,y\mid  wx=yw\rangle.$$ With the same $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ assigned as above, Riley's work shows this indeed gives us an $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$-representation if $s$ and $t$ satisfy the Riley's equation $f(s,t)=0$. When the degree of $f(s,t)$ is larger than 4, we cannot produce an explicit formula as above. But we can almost ensure there are uncountably many such $s,t$ with $f(s,t)=0$ (at least for certain subfamilies of 2-bridge knots).

Can we ensure there is at least one faithful $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$-representation among them?